# What is faster/more efficient - $(".selector").height() vs $(".selector").eq(0).height()

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-selectors

I have 20 x element.selector with **same** (`100px`) height and I need to get their height (`100px`, not `2000px`).

What is faster/more efficient to do?

```
$(".selector").height()
```

or

```
$(".selector").eq(0).height()
```

Comment: Why are you asking us? "If you want to know which horse is faster, race them!"

Comment: There is no difference. `height` returns height of the first element in the collection. If you have many `.selector` element, add an id to the target element and use an ID selector. In this case selector matters.

Comment: Are you really wondering to battle for nano seconds? It could matter if you are calling it thousand times in a row but then, there would be surely better way to handle your expecting behaviour. Use the code you find the most readable/maintainable. Don't pre-optimize any code, never

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I raced them for you.

```
            run 1           run 2           run 3           run 4
with_eq:    1956.769ms      1875.220ms      1930.814ms      1895.359ms
no_eq:      1851.168ms      1861.596ms      1804.347ms      1829.207ms
```

And it seems, that **not using** `eq(0)` is slightly faster. It's obvious, because you save another function call on your jquery object. Not calling something is always faster than to call.

This is my test case:

```js
// noprotect

console.time('with_eq');
for (var i = 0; i<40000; i++) {
  $(".foo").eq(0).height();
}
console.timeEnd('with_eq');

console.time('no_eq');
for (var i = 0; i<40000; i++) {
  $(".foo").height();
}
console.timeEnd('no_eq');
```

```css
    .foo { height:100px }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="foo">Hi.</div><div class="foo">Hi.</div><div class="foo">Hi.</div>
 <div class="foo">Hi.</div><div class="foo">Hi.</div><div class="foo">Hi.</div>
 <div class="foo">Hi.</div><div class="foo">Hi.</div><div class="foo">Hi.</div>
 <div class="foo">Hi.</div><div class="foo">Hi.</div><div class="foo">Hi.</div>
 <div class="foo">Hi.</div><div class="foo">Hi.</div><div class="foo">Hi.</div>
 <div class="foo">Hi.</div><div class="foo">Hi.</div><div class="foo">Hi.</div>
 <div class="foo">Hi.</div><div class="foo">Hi.</div><div class="foo">Hi.</div>
 <div class="foo">Hi.</div><div class="foo">Hi.</div><div class="foo">Hi.</div>
 <div class="foo">Hi.</div><div class="foo">Hi.</div><div class="foo">Hi.</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that's because `eq(0)` is a function call which is not necessary and doesn't change the result.

Comment: I raced them too (multiple times) http://jsperf.com/class-vs-class-eq-0-perfomance and most of the time $(".class") is faster than $(".class").eq(0)

Comment: @psyduck.the.apex.predator Because ya, one less function call

Comment: Guess I just thought that if I use .eq(0) then js wont have to go through all of the elements with the same class and check if they have same height, but that probably happens anyway, so using .eq(0) has no effect other than adding another task for js to run.